# What type of pins do H13 headlight sockets use?

Tags: wiring

I'm changing out the headlights in my 2004 Jeep to something more modern that require H13 sockets.

I purchased some OEM H13 pigtail connectors, but I would much rather prefer to cut off my H4 harness and crimp the H13 socket directly onto the wiring harness.

Does anyone know what type of pins are inside the H13 connector, so I can buy those to crimp directly, rather than splicing the OEM pigtail onto the wire.

Thanks!

Comment: The end [looks like this](http://contentinfo.autozone.com/znetcs/additional-prod-images/en/US/syl/H13/7/image/3/).

Comment: I'm looking for the little metal pieces shown here - http://www.ebay.com/itm/272253511670?_trksid=p2060353.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT